# Import/merge data from multiple sheets and then re-sort it intermixedly?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to have a Google Sheet that imports all data from multiple sheets but which can then be sorted in an intermixed way in the combined sheet?

I'm creating a spreadsheet for tracking the performance of a bunch of runners across multiple track meets.  I've got one sheet for each track meet, and I want to make one combined sheet that has all of the records but that I can sort by whatever parameter I want; e.g. by runner name, by time, by overall performance rank.

Is this possible?  I tried writing an `=QUERY` command like this (where the individual sheets are named after years, i.e. '2022' or '2021'):

`=QUERY({'2022'!B1:M;'2021'!B2:M},"Select * where Col2 is not null ORDER BY Col10 asc, Col11 asc")`

Even with the `ORDER BY` directive the `QUERY` output still has the sheet '2022' rows before '2021' rows.  Sorting by another column doesn't change that.

**Is there something that lets you merge multiple sheets in a way that lets the records intermingle?**

Or is the only way for me to make this work to instead have one "master" sheet and then make the individual meet sheets just be a filter on that?  I was hoping to have individual sheets be the source-of-truth :-/.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula will sort the data first by column `K` and then by column `L`, because `ColX` type identifiers are numbered starting at the first data column. `Col1` will refer to column `B` and `Col10` will refer to column `K` rather than column `J` as you may expect.

Note that you have left the `headers` parameter unspecified, which means that `query()` will try and deduce the number of header rows automatically, which sometimes causes trouble.

To sort by columns `J` and `K` instead, explicitly specifying the number of header row as `1`, use this:

`=query( { '2022'!B1:M; '2021'!B2:M }, "where Col2 is not null order by Col9, Col10", 1 )`

Alternatively, keep all the data in the same sheet and use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to decide which rows to show at a time. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

Comment: My issue isn't which columns happen to be sorted - it's that when I sort by them (either through the `ORDER BY` or by clicking on a column) the contents from '2022' and '2021' sheets aren't intermingled.  The contents from distinct sheets is kept separate from one another.  (I.e. all of the 20 rows from the '2022' sheet come before the 20 rows from the '2021' sheet, no matter what sorting I use.)

Comment: The formula I gave you will sort the data without considering which sheet a particular row happens to come from. Chances are that your _data_ is such that it sorts that way. Look for things like leading space characters. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.